# replace no numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tenho um dataset de frases e como faço para utilizar um replace no array do numpy
EX

```
x = array(['mais uma vez, o Sr. Costner arrumou um filme por muito mais tempo do que o necessário desse filme.])

palavras_retirar = ['filme', 'mais'] 

for i in palavras_retirar:
    x = x.replace(i, '')
```

Comment: np.char.replace(x, 'mais', '')  -> consegui usar o replace do numpy mas ele não tem opção por 'nada'

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `replace` mesmo, porém deverá especificar o elemento da lista, ou percorrer por toda ela mudando as palavras:

```
x = array(['mais uma vez, o Sr. Costner arrumou um filme por muito mais tempo do que o necessário desse filme.'])
         
palavras_retirar = ['filme', 'mais'] 

for i in palavras_retirar:
    x[0] = x[0].replace(i, '')
```

no seu código você tentou utilizar o `replace` na array inteira.

**ou**

utilizar o numpy.core.defchararray:

```
x = np_f.replace(x, 'filme', '')
x = np_f.replace(x, 'mais', '')
```